# How can I find symmetric difference in the words in two strings in C?

Tags: c, string

For example I have two strings:

```
lihuayu zhangxuehui sunyunlei guolei fuwenxia
lihuayu lixin fuwenxia zhangxuehui
```

And I will get

```
sunyunlei guolei lixin
```

I wrote following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define STRINGSIZE 64
void main()
{
    char *line1 = NULL;
    char *line2 = NULL;

    size_t size1;
    size_t size2;

    getline(&line1, &size1, stdin);
    getline(&line2, &size2, stdin);

    char*  spilted1 = strtok(line1, " ");

    while (spilted1 != NULL){
        if (strstr(line2, spilted1) == NULL){
            printf("%s", spilted1);
        }
        spilted1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

}
```

But it's obviously wrong in that I can't get those distinct words in `string2`.

I know how to do it in Python but have no idea how to do it in C.

Comment: Initialize `size1` and `size2` to zero too for safety.  You'll need two arrays of char pointers, one for each line of input.  You'll split the first line into the first array, and the second line into the second array.  Then you'll go through the two arrays of pointers, comparing strings and counting only those that do not match any of the entries in the other array.  (What do you do if one input line itself contains repeats — `The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe` for example?  Also, do you need to treat `The` as the same as `the` in that example?)

Comment: You can use `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()` if you have them available; at a pinch, you could use `strtok()`, but it is dangerous to use that in library code.  And you'll need to use `strcmp()` to compare the strings — plus macros/functions from `<ctype.h>` to handle case-conversion if that's appropriate.

Comment: Also note that `strtok()` is destructive.  If you've split string 1 with it, you can't then search in string 1 when you split string 2.  Also note that `strstr("then came a deluge", "the")` matches, even though most people would not regard the haystack string as containing the needle word `the`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks very much for your help , I am new to c and wonder there are something similar between c and python . I will check what you suggest , Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_WORDS = 64 };

static int split_words(char *buffer, char **words, int max_words)
{
    char *token;
    char *next = buffer;
    int num_words = 0;
    while ((token = strtok(next, " \n")) != 0 && num_words < max_words)
    {
        words[num_words++] = token;
        next = NULL;
    }
    return num_words;
}

static int word_in_list(char *word, char **list, int list_size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(word, list[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Print words in list w1 that do not appear in list w2 */
static void print_unique(char **w1, int n1, char **w2, int n2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        if (!word_in_list(w1[i], w2, n2))
            printf("[%s]\n", w1[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char  *line1 = NULL;
    char  *line2 = NULL;
    size_t size1 = 0;
    size_t size2 = 0;

    if (getline(&line1, &size1, stdin) > 0 &&
        getline(&line2, &size2, stdin) > 0)
    {
        char *w1[MAX_WORDS];
        char *w2[MAX_WORDS];
        int   n1 = split_words(line1, w1, MAX_WORDS);
        int   n2 = split_words(line2, w2, MAX_WORDS);

        print_unique(w1, n1, w2, n2);
        print_unique(w2, n2, w1, n1);
    }
    free(line1);
    free(line2);
    return 0;
}

/*
   You'll need two
   arrays of char pointers, one for each line of input.  You'll split the
   first line into the first array, and the second line into the second
   array.  Then you'll go through the two arrays of pointers, comparing
   strings and counting only those that do not match any of the entries in
   the other array.  (What do you do if one input line itself contains
   repeats — The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe for example?  Also, do
   you need to treat The as the same as the in that example?)

   You can use strtok_r() or strtok_s() if you have them available; at a
   pinch, you could use strtok(), but it is dangerous to use that in
   library code.  And you'll need to use strcmp() to compare the strings
   — plus macros/functions from <ctype.h> to handle case-conversion if
   that's appropriate.

   Also note that strtok() is destructive.  If you've split string 1 with
   it, you can't then search in string 1 when you split string 2.  Also
   note that strstr("then came a deluge", "the") matches, even though most
   people would not regard the haystack string as containing the needle
   word the.
 */
```

The algorithm used is quadratic in the number of words (it runs in O(N<sup>2</sup>) time); it compares each unique word in one list with every word in the other list.  You can do things like sort the lists and eliminate duplicates (in O(N.log N) time), and then step through the two lists to find unique words in linear time.  Being quadratic won't matter for tens of words, and probably not for hundreds of words, but would probably begin to matter after that.

Compilation:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -Werror uniq_words.c -o uniq_words
$
```

Example run:

```
$ cat data
lihuayu zhangxuehui sunyunlei guolei fuwenxia
lihuayu lixin fuwenxia zhangxuehui
$ uniq_words < data
[sunyunlei]
[guolei]
[lixin]
$
```

The square brackets around the data reassure me that the strings contain what I think they should contain.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **split(const char *str, const char *delimiter, size_t *len);
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b);
void find_diff(char **a1, char **a2);
void drop(char **a);

int main(void){
    char *line1 = NULL, *line2 = NULL;
    size_t size1 = 0, size2 = 0;

    getline(&line1, &size1, stdin);
    getline(&line2, &size2, stdin);

    //(1)split
    size_t len1, len2;
    char **array1 = split(line1, " \t\n", &len1);
    char **array2 = split(line2, " \t\n", &len2);

    //(2)sort
    qsort(array1, len1, sizeof(*array1), cmp);
    qsort(array2, len2, sizeof(*array2), cmp);

    //(3)compare
    find_diff(array1, array2);

    drop(array1);drop(array2);
    free(line1);free(line2);

    return 0;
}

char **split(const char *str, const char *delimiter, size_t *len){
    char *text, *p, *first, **array, **ret;
    size_t c;

    *len = 0;

    text = strdup(str);//make clone
    if(text == NULL) return NULL;

    for(c = 0, p = text; p = strtok(p, delimiter); p = NULL)
        ++c;//count elements

    ret = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(c+1));//+1 for NULL
    if(ret==NULL){
        free(text);
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(text, str);//restore
    array=ret;

    for(p = text; p = strtok(p, delimiter); p = NULL)
        *array++ = strdup(p);
    *array = NULL;
    *len = c;
    free(text);

    return ret;
}

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}

void find_diff(char **a1, char **a2){//arguments has been sorted
    while(*a1 || *a2){
        if(*a1 && a1[1] && !strcmp(*a1, a1[1])){
            ++a1;//distinct
            continue;
        }
        if(*a2 && a2[1] && !strcmp(*a2, a2[1])){
            ++a2;
            continue;
        }

        if(*a1 == NULL){
            puts(*a2++);
        } else if(*a2 == NULL){
            puts(*a1++);
        } else {
            int result;
            if((result=strcmp(*a1, *a2)) < 0){
                puts(*a1++);
            } else if(result > 0){
                puts(*a2++);
            } else {
                ++a1;
                ++a2;
            }
        }
    }
}

void drop(char **a){
    char **tmp = a;
    while(*a)
        free(*a++);
    free(tmp);
}
```